# cookie created in some strange way

Tags: cookies

I have the following code, the problem is. As far as i know. No cookie should be created?

What is happening when i visit the page. A empty cookie is created.

I am creating the cookie at logon page, then checking for the cookie at this page with the code below. Can some explain what is wrong here?

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["cookieName"] == null)
        {
            lblCookieYesNo.Text = "NO COOKIE!";
        }
        else
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["cookieName"].Value == "")
            {
                lblCookieYesNo.Text = "NO COOKIE VALUE!";
            }
            else
            {
                generateDiv("");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

"Response" needed to be "request".

It's working now.